# I am unable to display images in my react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, vite

```jsx
const Movie = ({ category, img, title, year, icon, rating }) => {
  return (
    <div className="movie-content">
      <img
        src="./assets/images/thumbnails/beyond-earth/regular/large.jpg"
        className="movie-image"
      />
      <div className="movie-info">
        <p>{year}</p>
        <img className="clip" src={icon} />
        <p>{category}</p>
        <p>{rating}</p>
      </div>
      <p className="movie-title">{title}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Movie;
```

```jsx
import Movie from "./Movie";
import data from "../contexts/data.json";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import uuid from "react-uuid";

const Movies = () => {
  const [getMovies, setGetMovies] = useState(data);

  const movie = getMovies.map((movie) => (
    <Movie
      key={uuid()}
      category={movie.category}
      title={movie.title}
      img={movie.thumbnail.regular.large}
      icon={movie.thumbnail.regular.small}
      year={movie.year}
      rating={movie.rating}
    />
  ));

  return (
    <div className="movie-cateogry">
      <h2 className="category-title">Trending</h2>
      <div className="popular-movies">{movie}</div>
      <h2 className="category-title">Recommended for you</h2>
      <div className="recommended">{movie}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Movies;
```

[image: src files path]

I tried using the data.json file to display the img. I also made the src to the direct path of the image.
I am having issues displaying any type of image in any one of my react components.
I usually have to import the images before they can get displayed. Am I needing to install something in order to display the images ?

Comment: What build system are you using eg `react-scripts`, Vite, Webpack, etc? They all have their own way of dealing with static assets

Comment: Using relative URLs could be problematic. If you are using routing of some kind, it's going to be relative to whatever is in the address bar. That is usually not the top level

Comment: I am using vite @phil, not using relative URLs

Comment: Please see https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets